# Unable to find a default constructor to use for type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.DynamicViewData

Tags: json.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, stackexchange.redis

I am getting this error when trying to Deserialize the string from the redis cache using Newtonsoft.Json.

where HeaderTopViewComponent is model class of one of my view component ""

like:  `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HeaderTopViewComponent>(cacheValue.Result.ToString());`

Unable to find a default constructor to use for type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.DynamicViewData. Path 'ViewBag', line 1, position 340.

Output string :

```
{"ShowTopheaderSection":true,"PageHeader":"MSHSL","FriendlyURL":"/MSHSL","leagueList":[{"leagueId":0,"FriendlyURL":"/","leaguename":"--Select--"},{"leagueId":3,"FriendlyURL":"/MSHSL","leaguename":"MSHSL"},{"leagueId":4,"FriendlyURL":"/CHSAA","leaguename":"CHSAA"}],"HttpContext":null,"Request":null,"User":null,"RouteData":null,"ViewBag":{},"ModelState":{},"Url":null,"ViewComponentContext":{"Arguments":null,"HtmlEncoder":null,"ViewComponentDescriptor":{"DisplayName":null,"FullName":null,"Id":"9882d08a-1c50-4c59-8a30-2d9c843957e9","ShortName":null,"TypeInfo":null,"MethodInfo":null},"ViewContext":{"FormContext":null,"ClientValidationEnabled":false,"Html5DateRenderingMode":0,"ValidationSummaryMessageElement":null,"ValidationMessageElement":null,"ViewBag":{},"View":null,"ViewData":{},"TempData":null,"Writer":null,"ExecutingFilePath":null,"ActionDescriptor":null,"HttpContext":null,"ModelState":{},"RouteData":null},"ViewData":{},"Writer":null},"ViewContext":{"FormContext":null,"ClientValidationEnabled":false,"Html5DateRenderingMode":0,"ValidationSummaryMessageElement":null,"ValidationMessageElement":null,"ViewBag":{},"View":null,"ViewData":{},"TempData":null,"Writer":null,"ExecutingFilePath":null,"ActionDescriptor":null,"HttpContext":null,"ModelState":{},"RouteData":null},"ViewData":{},"ViewEngine":null}
```

Comment: You cannot deserialize to objects that do not have a default constructor unless you write a custom type converter.

Answer (score 1):

I have fix it by adding some tag in my viewcomponent modal class and get set property like

`[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]` and `[JsonProperty]`

```
 //Tag to add only selected property when Deserialize or Serialize using Newtonsoft
    [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class HeaderTopViewComponent:ViewComponent
    {
        #region //Property//
        [JsonProperty]
        public bool ShowTopheaderSection { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty]
        public string PageHeader { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty]
        public string FriendlyURL { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty]
```

And now its working